# Why paginate plugin and skip/limit don't work in that mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
const paginateScheme = new Schema({

        posts: [ { img: String, description: String, liked: String, postComId: String, comments: [ { author: String, text: String } ] } ],
    }, {collection: "usersData"});

paginateScheme.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
const myModel  = mongoose.model("sample", paginateScheme);


app.put("/api/pagination", function(req, res){

    const options = {
        page: 1,
        limit: 3,
        collation: {
            locale: 'en',
        },
    };

    const query = User.find({mail: 'user2@example.com'}, {posts: 1 });


    myModel.paginate(  query , options, function (err, result) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

where post array of objects which I want to paginate.
I checked this plugin works correctly. When I use Model.find({}) it paginates through outer objects without any problems. I tried to use skip + limit but it returned nothing.

```
this query returns:
{
  docs: [ { _id: 601a8f013d86dc237468467c, posts: [Array] } ],
  totalDocs: 1,
  limit: 3,
  totalPages: 1,
  page: 1,
  pagingCounter: 1,
  hasPrevPage: false,
  hasNextPage: false,
  prevPage: null,
  nextPage: null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can using `$slice` for paginate a array like this(use async/await)

```
let result = await myModel.find({mail: 'user2@example.com'}, {posts: {$slice: [0, 3]}})
```